# "Happened to" or "Happened for"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

If I am explaining and listing events that happened to someone or concern them in some way, should I say:

> This is a list of events that happened to person x.

or

> This is a list of events that happened for person x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- this is a list of events that happened **to** mr/mrs...
- happen **for**, can be used ( for instance) to explain the reasons why these events happened,

Examples:

- These kind of things always happen **to him  for** the fact that he is an inattentive person.
- This tragedy happened for unknown reason.

Comment: So this is a rather common mistake, to say, "this happened for us, because we didn't try hard", right?

Comment: This happened to us, is the for to use in this case. This happened for us, gives the idea of something that was done on purpose for us, but in that case I'd say. This was 'done/put in place' for us.